# Using Firebase transaction block Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

In my firebase database I have a value stored

```
"1,2,6,1"
```

On the iphone I want to read that text and then +1 one of the number for example I want to start with

```
"1,2,6,1" --> and write "1,3,6,1" to the server.
```

Reading and writing is very simple however over 10 people could be editing this at the exact same time and I need to make sure that nobody adding a "+1" get's missed.

If I use a single event listener to get the string, how can I use a transaction block to write the appended data back up?

```
databaseRef.child("games").child("\(currentGameID!)").child("answers").child(currentTeamID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let teamScoreStringValue = snapshot.value as? String // "1,2,6,1"

        How to I write up "1,3,6,1"?

})
```

Comment: What does *however over 10 people could be editing this at the exact same time* exactly mean? They *edit* the same time, they *send the data* the same time? The data *is completely received* at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a Firebase database transaction for that. For more info and a good example, I recommend reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

I also recommend considering if your current data model is the best match for your use-case. If your users should be able to modify individual values in the string, it makes more sense to store the individual values in your database.